# SQL error - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with this SQL,
    -> );
    ERROR 1075 (42000): Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME12
(
TAB_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

NAME_FIRST NVARCHAR(200),
TYPE NVARCHAR(200)

);
```

I am using mysql, how can I solve this. I am trying to create a table. and I get this error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simular result you'll get with

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME12
(
  TAB_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME_FIRST NVARCHAR(200),
  TYPE NVARCHAR(200),
  PRIMARY KEY( TAB_ID )
);
```

This is also usable with other db's as mysql except the type definition int and nvarchar.
if you use varchar and integer instead you are compatible with postgresql.

Comment: Is it a must to specify Primary key ?

Comment: If the file should be an auto_increment then yes.

Answer (score 10):

You must specify `AUTO_INCREMENT` column as `PRIMARY KEY` try:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME12
(
 TAB_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 NAME_FIRST NVARCHAR(200),
 TYPE NVARCHAR(200)
);
```

Answer (score 8):

As Error Says.

```
"Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be 
defined as a key"
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e064

Add primary key on auto_increment column.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME12
(
TAB_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NAME_FIRST NVARCHAR(200),
TYPE NVARCHAR(200),
PRIMARY KEY (TAB_ID)
);
```